# Add buttons clicks or ontouch in array or db to repeat the same action in android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a drum pad app I want to record the user clicks on buttons and save them in ArrayList  or database when the user clicks the record button and simulate the same clicks programmatically to mix them 
I am  Using Soundpool and on touch Event

I spent many hours searching but nothing found.

Code  :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

Button btn_1, btn_2, btn_3, btn_4, btn_5, btn_6, btn_7, btn_8, btn_9, btn_10, btn_11, btn_12, rec_btn; 
SoundPool sp;
int sound_1, sound_2, sound_3, sound_4, sound_5, sound_6, sound_7, sound_8, sound_9, sound_10, sound_11, sound_12;
boolean isRecording = false;
SeekBar seekBar;
int progress;
float sp_flot = 1f; 
long startTime;
private final int MAX_STREAM = 10;
Animation anim;

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        sp = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
                .setMaxStreams(MAX_STREAM)
                .build();
    } else {
        sp = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }



    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(500); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
    anim.setStartOffset(200);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn_5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn_6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn_7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    btn_8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    btn_9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    btn_10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn10);
    btn_11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn11);
    btn_12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn12);
    rec_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rec_btn);
    btn_1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_3.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_4.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_5.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_6.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_7.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_8.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_9.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_10.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_11.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btn_12.setOnTouchListener(this);

    sound_1 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_01, 1);
    sound_2 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_02, 1);
    sound_3 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_03, 1);
    sound_4 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_04, 1);
    sound_5 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_05, 1);
    sound_6 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_06, 1);
    sound_7 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_07, 1);
    sound_8 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_08, 1);
    sound_9 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_09, 1);
    sound_10 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_10, 1);
    sound_11 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_11, 1);
    sound_12 = sp.load(this, R.raw.drum_12, 1);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            double fm = (double) progress / 10;
            sp_flot = (float) fm;


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });



    rec_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isRecording)  {
                rec_btn.startAnimation(anim);
                isRecording = true;

            } else  {
                 rec_btn.clearAnimation();
                isRecording = false; 

            }

        }
    });

}




@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);


    int v_id = v.getId();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            switch (v_id) {
                case R.id.btn1:



                    btn_1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                   sp.play(sound_1, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);



                    break;
                case R.id.btn2:
                    btn_2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_1, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);




                    break;
                case R.id.btn3:


                    btn_3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_3, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);


                    break;
                case R.id.btn4: 

                    btn_4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_4, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot); 

                    break;
                case R.id.btn5:

                    btn_5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_5, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);


                    break;
                case R.id.btn6: 
                    btn_6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_6, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);


                    break;
                case R.id.btn7: 
                    btn_7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_7, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);

                    break;
                case R.id.btn8: 
                    btn_8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_5, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);

                    break;
                case R.id.btn9: 
                    btn_9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_9, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);


                    break;
                case R.id.btn10:
                     btn_10.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_9, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);

                    break;
                case R.id.btn11:
                     btn_11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_11, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);

                    break;
                case R.id.btn12:
                     btn_12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    sp.play(sound_12, 1, 1, 1, 0, sp_flot);


                    break;
            }


            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            switch (v_id) {
                case R.id.btn1:
                    btn_1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn2:
                    btn_2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn3:
                    btn_3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn4:
                    btn_4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn5:
                    btn_5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn6:
                    btn_6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn7:
                    btn_7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn8:
                    btn_8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn9:
                    btn_9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn10:
                    btn_10.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn11:
                    btn_11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
                case R.id.btn12:
                    btn_12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                     break;
            }

            break; 
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Please provide the code what have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store touch event, rather save sound id being played with time stamp, later you can play them in sequence. you can share this data among users as well and it will play same on different devices.